# how to get TIMECODE from a FRAME?

Tags: video, google-sheets, frame-rate

I attempting to convert frame into timecode based on framerate.

example 1:

framerate is: **23.976 fps** (C1)

video frame is: **145068** (C2)

and a timecode for that is **01:40:50.544000000**

format of the timecode is: **HH:MM:SS.nnnnnnnnn** (hours:minutes:seconds:nanoseconds)

-

**EDIT 1:**
thank you @Sangbok Lee / @Owen Campbell

now I see that I maybe choosed wrong approach in my logic (because @Sangbok Lee's answer cant be wrong with "given" data)... I asumed that if I know FPS and FRAMERATE I could easily convert FRAME into TIMECODE but it looks like I am wrong somewhere...

example 2: my video file (mkv) fps is 23.976. video contains chapters (xml) and one of the chaptermarks says 01:40:50.544000000. now if I jump on that chaptermark in my videoplayer (potplayer) and check the frame it says that I am on 145068th frame.

point is that if I grab same video file (which now does not have chapters) and I know the frame (145068) where I want to have a "chapter start", how can I get this - 01:40:50.544000000 TIMECODE ?? <- thats my real question

**EDIT 2:**

I just figured it out that 23,976 is "fake" number. the real fps is 24000/1001 which is 23.976023976023976023976023976024 and with @Sangbok Lee's formula it gives me **01:40:50.544500000** which I believe its a real deal. -> [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1L9Zw6KHbb4f5uS1XFamdM2mQzAmAsucmI8uqAPcjV_M/edit#gid=1955729369)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's divide this complicated problem into parts.

1. set `E2`(hh) to `=roundDown(C2/(3600*C1))`
2. set `F2`(mm) to `=roundDown((C2-(E2*(3600*C1)))/(60*C1))`
3. set `G2`(ss) to `=roundDown((C2-(E2*(3600*C1))-(F2*(60*C1)))/C1)`
4. set `H2`(n...n) to `=round((C2-(E2*(3600*C1))-(F2*(60*C1))-(G2*C1))/C1*1000000000)`. The formula you used is not for nanoseconds. It's for frames.
5. Now concatenate these. set `I2` to:

`=if(len(E2)=1, "0"&E2, E2)&":"&
  if(len(F2)=1, "0"&F2, F2)&":"&
  if(len(G2)=1, "0"&G2, G2)&"."&
  rept("0", 9-len(H2))&H2`

6. The result is `00:10:23.832165499`. It's the same as **Owen Campbell**'s answer (`00:10:23.832`) so I think your first calculation was wrong. Sample sheet is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1L9Zw6KHbb4f5uS1XFamdM2mQzAmAsucmI8uqAPcjV_M/).

Comment: Thanks, I changed that `:` to `.`. And yes I know there are more simple and elegant solutions. I admire that. :) I just stuck to OP's original approach.

Comment: thx, your solution helped me to understand how to get those nanoseconds, however pls see my edit of my post

Comment: Seeking video files is not a trivial task since its based on 'key frames' not on a single frame. It's another question about how video players like PotPlayer deal with the chapter marks and/or timecodes. (And I suspect that the last part of timecode is for frames not nanoseconds.)

Comment: with 23.976023976023976023976023976024 it suddenly works. yes, it could be true that potplayer handles it with rounded approximation due to floating/dynamic fps. with few more tests i got results from 50.543000000 up to 50.545000000 but never less/more than that, and 145067th frame is ~50.502000000 and 145069th frame is ~50.587000000 so I am satisfied :) ty

Answer (score 1):

A simpler method is with the formula:

`=TEXT( C2 / LEFT(C1,LEN(C1)-4) / 86400, "hh:mm:ss.000" )`

It doesn't quite give nanoseconds though.

This formula takes the video frame and divides it by the framerate to get the number of seconds that have elapsed. This is divided by 86400 (the number of seconds in a day) to get a percentage of a day elapsed. The TEXT function can format this as a timestamp.

To get the framerate, I remove that last 4 characters from the cell (`fps`) with the LEFT formula.

Edit:

It seems difficult to properly display nanoseconds in Excel as discussed [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_win10-mso_2016/can-excel-display-nanosecond-stamped-data/82395c9e-201e-4afc-a7b8-b3ae7700e52b). Is that a necessary requirement?

Edit 2:

Using [pnut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49567461/how-to-get-timecode-from-a-frame/49567578#comment86144062_49567745)'s superior method combined with parsing the number out of your fps cell, the following formula works:

`=TEXT(((C2/LEFT(C1, LEN(C1)-4))-MOD(C2/LEFT(C1, LEN(C1)-4),60))/86400,"hh:mm:")&MOD(C2/LEFT(C1, LEN(C1)-4),60)`

Comment: I've updated my answer with a version that also calculates nanoseconds and still only uses a single cell.

Comment: Oh, good point. I don't want to steal your formula in that case. You ought to make a top level answer as yours is the current best.